# Loop to visible items in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is possible to loop to the visible items in a ng-repeat? 
I have a ng-repeat with multiple filters and I want to create a 'select all' function to select all the visible items in the repeat.

How can I get the visible items? The selection may be come undone when the filter is changing, so there are no 'old' selections possible, but that can be easily done to loop all items with no conditional.

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat='item in collection | product_sex:filter_sex | product_stock: stockKind | filter:productFilter'>
    {{item.name}}
    {{item.price}}
</div>
```

Comment: Show your code. What have you tried?

Comment: Still nothing, I have no idea where to start. I have added the ng-repeat

Comment: Any reason to not using a binding ? Maybe I'm wrong but only unfiltered element, i.e. visible in the list, will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a filter like this;

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{visible: true} ">
    <p>{{item.id}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a variable that represents all visible items by using ***as*** expression with a ng-repeat directive:

```
<div class="item" 
     ng-repeat='item in (collection | product_sex:filter_sex | product_stock: stockKind | filter:productFilter) as allVisibleItems'>
    {{item.name}}
    {{item.price}}
</div>
```

You could access this variable easily, right underneath ng-repeat for example:

```
<div ng-click="selectAll(allVisibleItems)">Select all Items</div>
```

More can be read here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat